# Not able to add repo when APT is using a proxy connection

Tags: apt, proxy, add-apt-repository

I have ubuntu 12.10 working on my system. I have tried many time to add repo but every time i tried i got the same error as in this case.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa
Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~scopes-packagers/+archive/ppa) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.
```

my net is working fine. apt-get install is also working.

so why is it giving error that check your internet connection? 
( i am working under proxy server with authentication)

```
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf file

Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@172.31.100.29:3128/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@172.31.100.29:3128/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@172.31.100.29:3128/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://username:password@172.31.100.29:3128/";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved in a thread in the Ubuntu forums. Look [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1599832) and scroll to the bottom.

Comment: thnx for your help.

Comment: I feel a little bit stupid, but I don't really understand what I have to do in order to make it work...
What should I write in "export https_proxy=...."?

Answer (score 0):

Only set http_proxy env variable is not enough. https_proxy is also required.

And I was needed to execute the add-apt-repository command **as root, NOT via sudo.**
 i don't know why it is not working with sudo but as root is working fine..

Comment: You can use sudo but need to provide the "-E" option, like "sudo -E add-apt-repository ..." to preserve the environment variables, otherwise, sudo start a clean session.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "network" settings panel (System Settings->Network), click on "Network Proxy", and set the proxy server/port info for http & https, then click "Apply system wide"